# Open new window without security confirmation?

Tags: javascript

*I use this code to open a new window in JS:*

```
let popupWinindow = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
popupWinindow.document.write(response);
```

So, if I do this first time the browser asks confirmation to open this window. It is not convenient to user, cause most people don't know when to permit this action. Also there are a lot browsers that does the same.

*Is it possible to unify this case without any security confirmations?*

Comment: No. Its a security feature. You can't disable it. Why would you put the content into a new window at all?

Comment: I do this: `window.open`  either you mean something else?

Comment: why window not new tab are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser will only let you open a new window if you are handling a user event such as a click event. It will not just let you open a window whenever you feel like it.

Something like the code below but it won't work here because the iframe that it runs on has been sandboxed but it should work on a top level page.

> Blocked opening 'about:blank' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.

```js
document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const win = window.open("about:blank");
  win.document.write("new win");
});
```

```html
<a href="#">click for new window</a>
```

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta I know it does, I explained it in the answer. Not sure what you are saying...